# Canadian citizen, working for a US-based company in Toronto. How will exercising my stock options work in terms of the IRS and the CRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, capital-gains-tax, employee-stock-options

I work for a US-based company, but in their Toronto, Canada offices. On a monthly basis, I receive some amount of stock options in the Private corporation, which is based in the USA. I can exercise these stock options at a later date.

My question is how do the tax implications work, if and when I decide to exercise my stock options? I know that I have to go through the IRS and the CRA, but I'm not sure how that would work. Any help is much appreciated!